# What's a good word for a lack of concentration?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective that describes not concentrated.

Something like "flying around", "not really here".

*In hebrew it would've been מעופף.*

Comment: "Brain fog" is a term used by many suffering from chronic fatigue symptoms.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The definitions are taken from the NOAD and OALD.

- **Distracted** *adj*. unable to concentrate because one's mind is preoccupied.
- **Absent-minded** *adj*. tending to forget things, perhaps because you are not thinking about what is around you, but about something else.
- **Inattentive** *adj*. not paying attention to something/somebody.

Answer (score 6):

I think a more simple word would go in this context and the right word to use (if you were to translate מעופף ) would be "daydreamer". You can say "He's such a daydreamer"

Answer (score 5):

How about [*absent-minded*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absent-minded)?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of:

- daydreaming
- with his/her head in the clouds
- not focused [on the task]
- lost in his/her thoughts

Answer (score 1):

**spacey** |ˈspeɪsi| (also **spacy**)
adjective (**spacier** |ˈspeɪsiər|, **spaciest** |ˈspeɪsi1st|) *informal*
out of touch with reality, as though high on drugs : *I remember babbling, high and spacey.*
• (of popular, esp. electronic music) drifting and ethereal.

<sup>-*NOAD*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If the person is thinking of something else, or engrossed in an activity, we say `He is preoccupied`.  If the person is engrossed in a memory, we say, `She is a million miles away.`

Answer (score 0):

Without more context it won't be easy to help, but "loose" is a fairly catch-all term for things that are not condensed. If you mean "not concentrating," then "distracted," etc., as given by others.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question is kind of mistaken. "Not concentrated" generally means "diffuse" or "diluted," but then in your explanation you don't mean "concentrated" in that sense. Concentrated almost always refers to the purity of some substance (especially a liquid) while you are talking about mental focus. In that case what you wanted to say is "not concentrat**ing**."

Comment: The OED actually lists *Having the faculties collected and directed to one object.* as the second definition of "concentrated" (the first being *Brought to or towards a common centre or focus*).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I meant more about general usage than the dictionary definition, so I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I agree with you that probably focused is less prone to be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

scatterbrained

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scatterbrained)

> (Of a person) disorganized and lacking in concentration.