# Describe a state where mental focus is spread too thin and/or on too wide a range of concerns?

Tags: word-choice, sentence

At my work when I have a myriad tasks, could I say that my thoughts are dispersed amongst many objectives? I am trying to figure if I could use the term dispersed in a sentence to describe a state where a persons thoughts are not focused because the range of issues that concern her is too wide to efficiently handle at once.

I read this: [What's a good word for a lack of concentration?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23301/whats-a-good-word-for-a-lack-of-concentration) but it was not very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the answers to the other question you linked were not helpful because they all had a negative connotation, like "scatterbrained" (which would have been my answer had I seen that question).

You are trying to describe the state of being *spread too thin*, because your many issues keep you from having a single-minded focus.

The tech-jargon-derived term for this is:

### [multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_multitasking)

where your processor (brain) shares many tasks which all get a time slice.

Comment: Or, "situation normal." :-)

Comment: I would say I was 'spreading myself too thinly'.

Comment: _Overextended_ is another good word for this.